# Undefined method/Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, image, graphics, japplet

I'm in the process of creating a simple game and I stumbled upon an error I can't resolve.
When trying to import/draw an image with Graphics an error pops up:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - getCenterX cannot be resolved or is not a field
    - getCenterY cannot be resolved or is not a field
    - getCenterY cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I'm most certain that I imported everything correctly:

### Declarations/Variables/Definitions

```
// In the class "StartingClass"
private Robot robot;
private URL base;

// In the class "Robot"
private int centerX = 100;
private int centerY = 328;
```

### Methods in the class "StartingClass"

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(character, robot.getCenterX()- 61, robot.getCenterY - 62, this);
    }

@Override
    public void start() {
        robot = new Robot();
    }
```

### Methods in the class "Robot"

```
public int getCenterX() {
        return centerX;
    }

public int getCenterY() {
        return centerY;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling that method in your code? I don't see it...

Comment: Also, what's the point of your thread? You never use it!

Comment: Is that supposed to be `java.awt.Robot` or your own class called `Robot`?

Comment: The solution suggested by Kayaman solved one problem, but there are still couple more: I still get the errors that the methods getCenterX/Y are not resolvable or are not fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
robot.getCenterY
```

I think the problem is this, as getCenterY is not a variable. Its a typo for the method getCenterY(). To fix, just add the parenthetical at the end.
Otherwise, please post more snippets as not much can be determined from your code provided.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.